# How can we use socket.io with Angular.?

Tags: angular, socket.io

This is my code. how can we use socket.io with Angular.?

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { createServer, Server } from 'http';

import * as express from 'express';

import * as socketIo from 'socket.io';





const SERVER_URL = 'localhost:4200';

@Component({




  selector: 'app-root',

  templateUrl: './app.component.html',

  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']

})

export class AppComponent {


  public static readonly PORT:number = 8080;

  private app: express.Application;

  private server: Server;

  **"private io: SocketIO.server;"**  ////at this line i get error that cannot find namespace SocketIO

  private port: string | number;


}
```

I am trying to use socket.io in my angular app. And I get the error in at the bold line.can any one help me that why I am getting this error?

Comment: This isn't about Angular. Read about TypeScript  if that's the language you're using

Answer (score 1):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-socket-io

```
npm install ngx-socket-io
```

better than ng-socket-io, because there will be no need in rxjs-compat.

Comment: Sorry, what is difference between ng-socket-io and ngx-socket-io?

Comment: @VitaliyMarkitanov ngx-socket-io uses rxjs v6 and it works fine in angular 6+ (maybe even 5+ i don't remember) projects. ng-socket-io uses rxjs v5 and you need to install rxjs-compat dependency in order to make ng-socet-io work in angular 6+ project.

Answer (score 0):

This isn´t the best way to use Socket.io, I recommend you to use this module

https://github.com/bougarfaoui/ng-socket-io

Install it in your project

```
npm install ng-socket-io
```

and then add it to your app module

```
import { SocketIoModule, SocketIoConfig } from 'ng-socket-io';

const config: SocketIoConfig = { url: 'http://localhost:8988', options: {} 
};

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    SocketIoModule.forRoot(config) 
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Then you'll be able to use it in a service extended from injectable.